# What's the naming convention for a boolean method setter in Swift?

Tags: swift, boolean, naming-conventions, swift5

Assuming I have a getter method and setter method for a boolean instead of property because I need to pass in a flag, what would the naming convention be for the setter method?

e.g.

```
func isEnabled(for feature: String) {

}

func setIsEnabled(value: bool, for feature: String) { ... }
```

or is it

```
func setEnabled(value: bool, for feature: String) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally like setEnabled function and passing true or false. This way you have one function and it is responsible for enabling or disabling the feature.

Answer (score 2):

The `is` prefix is a convention for properties, but there isn't a convention for get/set method pairs.

What you're looking for is *named subscripts*. But Swift doesn't have them. ☹️

You can emulate them, however.

It's very easy to do, if your logic doesn't depend on instance data:

```swift
struct Static {
  enum isEnabled {
    static subscript(for feature: String) -> Bool {
      get { .random()! }
      set { }
    }
  }
}

Static.isEnabled[for: ""] = true
Static.isEnabled[for: ""]
```

Otherwise, you need to use a class.

```swift
final class Instance {
  struct IsEnabled {
    fileprivate let instance: Instance

    subscript(for feature: String) -> Bool? {
      get { instance.dictionary[feature] }
      nonmutating set { instance.dictionary[feature] = newValue }
    }
  }

  var isEnabled: IsEnabled { .init(instance: self) }

  private var dictionary: [String: Bool] = [:]
}

let instance = Instance()
instance.isEnabled[for: ""] = true
instance.isEnabled[for: ""] // true

let isEnabled = instance.isEnabled
isEnabled[for: ""]  // true
isEnabled[for: ""] = false
instance.isEnabled[for: ""] // false
```

Comment: Wicked, very wicked.